# Binders in Prolog

Tags: lambda, prolog

I know Prolog has no built-in binders to represent e.g. `λx (x=1)` but I was wondering if it was possible to implement them. In some predicates like `setof/3`, the behaviour is quite close: the variable `X` in the answer substitution for the query

```
?- setof(X, member(X,[a,a,c]), Xs).
Xs = [a, c].
```

is unbound and we can give it a value to our liking:

```
?- setof(X, member(X,[a,a,c]), Xs), X = b.
X = b,
Xs = [a, c].
```

But if we instantiate `X` earlier, we lose solutions:

```
?- X = b, setof(X, member(X,[a,a,c]), Xs).
false.
```

What I would like to happen is that `setof` binds `X`, i.e. for the evaluation of `setof`, `X` is treated like a fresh variable. To make this a bit more concrete: Is it possible to give an implementation `binding_setof` such that

```
?- X = b, binding_setof(X, member(X,[a,a,c]), Xs).
X = b,
Xs = [a, c].
```

?

P.S.: I am aware of languages like λProlog which were built to solve this issue, but I am interested in a Prolog solution.

Edit:
I have tried to solve the problem with `library(lambda)`. I aimed to create an anonymous variable and apply it to `\X^setof(X, member(X,[a,c,c], Xs)` via `call/N`. Since the binding of `Xs` is undone outside of it, the toplevel does not report it. It's still possible to see it by adding `format('~w',[Xs])` into the setof but I leave it out for clarity. Again, the call

```
?- call(\X^setof(X,member(X,[a,c,c]),Xs), _), X=b.
X = b.
```

succeeds, but

```
?- X = b, call(\X^setof(X,member(X,[a,c,c]),Xs), _).
false.
```

fails. This is consistent with the comment in the source that a lambda bound variable must not occur outside the lambda expression.

Comment: There are some Prolog implementations of lambda calculus, like [this one](https://github.com/gustavderdrache/lambda). I'm not sure if it implements binders, though.

Comment: Thanks you, this looks quite interesting, but if I see it correctly, lambda variables are represented as constants. See e.g. ```apply(fun(x, x), y) reduces_to y.``` in the tests. I am looking for a solution where Prolog variables represent lambda variables, but this might be impossible.

Comment: Are you aware of `library(lambda)` for [SICStus](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/lambda.pl)|[SWI](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/file_details/lambda/prolog/lambda.pl)?

Comment: Yes, but I have always used it in the context of the built-in meta-predicates and as a black box. In so far my example with setof is also poorly chosen - I was more heading towards representing quantified formulas as terms and wanted to start slowly. I'll look into the implementation of library(lambda) though! Thanks!

Comment: I made an attempt with ```library(lambda)``` but it seems it requires a bound X not to occur outside the term. So I am still wondering, if we could lift this restriction.

Comment: Seems what you want is some form of more static scoping. So for example in `(X = 1, maplist(\X^Y^nimporte, Xs, Ys) )` there should be a warning/error. The trouble with this is only, no matter how you restrict it, you are scratching on the actual dynamic properties of Prolog.

Comment: I hadn't seen it in the sense of static vs. dynamic scoping but it is much to the point. I thought about (ab-)using attributed variables but it sounds more and more like a hack than a clean solution. Thanks for all the input!

Answer (score 3):

[The Golog interpreter](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/cogrobo/kia/gologinterpreter) contains a solution to locally scoping variables, they use a `pi/2` compound and a `sub/4` predicate. We can adapt `pi/2` to a predicate, their license precludes distributing their interpreter so you'll need to get `sub/4` from them (free), linked above.

```
pi(V, E) :- 
    sub(V, _, E, E1), 
    call(E1).

?- X = d, pi(x, setof(x, member(x, [a, a, c]), Xs)).
X = d,
Xs = [a, c].
```

It works "most of the time"; I've had issues when working with CLP libraries.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I like the trick substituting a fresh variable (even though it's clear that CLP implementations that use attributed variables don't get the attributes passed on). If I understand the definition of `sub/4` correctly, Prolog variables are also Golog variables, right? Just wondering because your example uses a constant`x` instead of a variable.

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe, also Golang is constrained by the boundaries of Prolog: if we want to know `holds(some(X, p(X) & all(X,Q(X)), Context)`, the `X` in `some(X,...)` might be substituted (if I understood the Lloyd-Topor transformation rule "∃x P rewrites to P" correctly, but that's from another paper) by a possibly ground term `t`. When we arrive at the evaluation of `all(X,...)`, it has already become `all(t, ...)` such that the renaming does not work anymore. My discussion with @false has left me to believe that we can't do much better without changing the Prolog in essential parts.

Comment: `pi/2` as above is a second-order predicate that takes an atom e.g. `x` and a predicate that uses `x` in place of a variable. In execution it substitutes the atom `x` in the predicate for a variable and calls the predicate. You cannot get the value `x` was unified to from `pi/2`, but it is locally scoped to the second argument of `pi/2`, which can contain unbound variables. `pi/2` as above is based on the idea in Golog, but doesn't touch the Llyod-Topper transformations, or any of `holds/2`. I just used `sub/4` from their interpreter.

Comment: Ah, I see - thanks for the explanation! In that case, one could adapt the definition of sub to take care of multiple bindings of the same variable (i.e. stop substituting `x` whenever we encounter a new binder as a subterm). -- This is then similar to the approach mentioned by @AndersonGreen